# Is this safe to assume non-https?

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-redirect

In my .htaccess file, I have created following rule to make sure it's always HTTPS:

```
# Redirect To HTTPS...
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Is it safe to assume that each port other than 443 should be redirected to HTTPS? Are other ports should also be allowed on specific occasions? I want my website to never be served unencrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Add below rule to your .htaccess it will make force https independent of the port and redirect all http traffic to https.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Would be a better example if you explained why - that filtering based on port selection is useless but instead filter on protocol used. But a good solution nonetheless.

Comment: Good thing with this HTTPS off! But using HTTP_HOST is bad idea, this value uses `host` header sent by the client - don't use it!

Comment: And one more thing - it's better to do `=off` instead of `off`. This is what people forget very often - without `=` it's a regular expression! It gives small performance drop, but it's not that important. Worse, it will also match `offside`, `ripoff` etc. Something to remember if we are going to use such values where there are more options than just on and off.

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` is sent in `host` header but rule is executed only when this header is valid and recognized by your `VirtualHost` entry. One can also use `%{SERVER_NAME}`.

Answer (score 1):

Port 80 and 443 are the default ports for HTTP/HTTPS as per the RFC documentaion http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt. So browsers will automatically use these ports to connect for these protocols. Port numbers will need to be provided to the browser if not 80/443.

So unless you have a reason to serve from non-standard ports you can redirect from port 80 to 443. You nned to be aware of using a catch all  redirect to 443 in case you start using another port for HTTP connections or equally using a port 80 redirect and then adding more ports for serving won't redirect.

There are many ways to write the redirect based on what suits your requirement.

An example of a port 80 redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Again. `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` is not port 80. It's port that CONTAINS "80" in its number. Is this what you meant? I guess not.

Comment: Plus, why are you catching regex from the uri if you don't need it? Use {REQUEST_URI} instead.

Comment: And last thing - you probably want to redirect permanently, not temporarily. Use R=301.

Answer (score 1):

unless explicitly ask to ,browsers will only connect to port 80 (or 443 if https specified). Your web server should be listening only to port 80 and 443, so you only have to redirect the port 80.

If you want you always serve https, then you should add HSTS and preload your website:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security

https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

HSTS is a header that tell to the browser to only connect to https, never http, but it only works after a first successful connection (so the first connection may be insecure). If you preload it, then the browsers know that your website only use https even before the first visits, so it can protect it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over Apache config and care about performance hits then there is no need to use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. This will avoid loading and parsing `.htaccess` for every web request.

Just use this simple `Redirect` directive in your virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Read more about: [when not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html)

Comment: Yeah, I already found it too. I will probably try to reflect my .htaccess rules in server configuration.